# Simple Spring Integration Test with Hive profile fails

Tags: spring, hadoop, testing, hive, spring-profiles

I have a two Spring profile configurations as shown below.

First is the application.yml:

```
management:
    security:
        roles: ADMIN
    context-path: /management
    health:
        mail:
            enabled: false # When using the MailService, configure an SMTP server and set this to true
spring:
    application:
        name: TfgJHipsterApp
    profiles:
        # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.
        # Otherwise, it will be filled in by gradle when building the WAR file
        # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
        active: #spring.profiles.active#
    jackson:
        serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps: false
    jpa:
        open-in-view: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
                implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    messages:
        basename: i18n/messages
    mvc:
        favicon:
            enabled: false
    thymeleaf:
        mode: XHTML

security:
    basic:
        enabled: false

server:
    session:
        cookie:
            http-only: true

info:
    project:
        version: #project.version#
```

Second, the application-hive.yml:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: hive
        include: no-liquibase
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
        type: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
        url: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0
        username: catalin
        password:
        default-auto-commit: true
    mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        username:
        password:
    messages:
        cache-seconds: 1
    thymeleaf:
        cache: false
liquibase:
    contexts: hive
```

In my default Hive database I have the following tables:

```
hive> show tables;
OK
jhi_authority
jhi_user
jhi_user_authority
pruebadetabla
sequences
Time taken: 0.062 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
hive>
```

I also have a pretty complex project (generated by JHipster) and what I want to do is implement a simple test running under the HIVE profile in order to test connectivity and run queries to the Hive Database. So in my test package I have the following test:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.own;

import com.mycompany.myapp.TfgJHipsterApp;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TfgJHipsterApp.class)
@ActiveProfiles("hive")
@Transactional
public class PersonalTests {

    @Test
    public void testPersonal() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
        Environment env = ctx.getEnvironment();
        boolean containsFoo = env.containsProperty("foo");
        System.out.println("Does my environment contain the 'foo' property? " + containsFoo);
    }
}
```

Actually, as you can see the test itself is not doing anything for now, but that's only because I get an error when trying to execute it. I will provide 
a stacktrace now, but as I can see the main problem I believe is that Application Context  could not be succesfully loaded and also that the table "sequences" could not be found... and as you can see in my Hive database, the table sequences actually DOES exist.

Stacktrace when trying to execute the test:

```
2017-07-17 13:00:14.647  INFO 20204 --- [           main] com.mycompany.myapp.own.PersonalTests    : Starting PersonalTests on catalin-GL552VW with PID 20204 (started by catalin in /home/catalin/Escritorio/TFG/TFG)
2017-07-17 13:00:14.647  INFO 20204 --- [           main] com.mycompany.myapp.own.PersonalTests    : The following profiles are active: no-liquibase,hive
2017-07-17 13:00:19.696  WARN 20204 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Method not supported
2017-07-17 13:00:21.359  WARN 20204 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 10001, SQLState: 42S02
2017-07-17 13:00:21.360 ERROR 20204 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
2017-07-17 13:00:21.361  WARN 20204 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-07-17 13:00:21.451 ERROR 20204 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:266)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:252)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:309)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:132)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:388)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:193)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:276)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:324)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:499)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:295)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:506)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1422)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genResolvedParseTree(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10826)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1229)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:191)
    ... 26 common frames omitted

2017-07-17 13:00:21.477 ERROR 20204 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4d2950ed] to prepare test instance [com.mycompany.myapp.own.PersonalTests@3095d06b]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:266)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:252)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:309)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:132)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:388)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:193)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:276)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:324)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:499)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:486)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:295)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:506)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1422)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:72 Table not found 'sequences'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genResolvedParseTree(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10826)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:477)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1229)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:191)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Here is the pastebin version (the previous stacktrace is not 100% complete): https://pastebin.com/dG2Hm8WU